# Adjacency like matrix structure in C

Tags: c, matrix, struct, linked-list

I need to implement a matrix inputted by user using two structures:

```
    typedef struct cellNode {
        int cell;
        struct cellNode* next;
}   Node;

typedef struct  {
        int numRows;
        int numColumns;
        Node** rows;
}   Matrix;
```

Matrix structure to hold matrix size and a pointer to the rows of the matrix.
each matrix->rows[i] will hold the row via linked Node list using the Node structure.

**Matrix**

|rows[0]|->|rows[0]->next|->|rows[0]->next->next|......

|rows[1]|->|rows[1]->next|->|rows[1]->next->next|......

|rows[2]|->|rows[2]->next|->|rows[2]->next->next|......

For this solution i need to malloc the matrix and the rows pointer, after that i should be able to simply add nodes based on the matrix->rows[i]->cell method, but it doesn't work.

I have searched a lot on the topic but cant seems to figure it out why i cant access the proper values and add nodes correctly. closest solution i have found on the internet is this :
https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-adjacency-list
my current code is

```
Matrix* MatrixAdder(int row, int col, char mat)
{
   int i,j;
   int value=0;
   Node* newNode=NULL;
   Matrix* temp = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
   if (temp==NULL)
       exit (1);
   temp->numRows=row;
   temp->numColumns=col;
   temp->rows = malloc(row * sizeof(Node*));
   if (temp->rows==NULL)
       exit(1);
   printf("Please insert values for matrix %c:\n",mat);
   for (i=0;i<row;i++)
   {
       printf("Enter row %d data\n",i);
       scanf("%d",&value);
       temp->rows[i]->cell=value;
       for (j=0;j<col-1;j++)
       {
           newNode=createNode();
           temp->rows[i]->next=newNode;
       }
   }


}

Node* createNode()
{
   int n;
   Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
   if (newNode==NULL)
       exit(1);
   newNode->cell=n;
   newNode->next = NULL;
   return newNode;
}
```

Comment: If you store a row as a linked list, you dont need to store the number of columns, it is just the number of nodes in the list.

Comment: @wildplasser I need the columns number for further calculations on the matrix.

Comment: But why are you wasting ~50% of your memory on pointers (and even more on CPU)? The matrix is not sparse.

Comment: @wildplasser where do you see wasted memory?  I allocate the number of rows in matrix->rows then for each row I want to allocate col number of nodes connected to each other via next pointer.

Comment: The `->next` pointers cost memory, too.

Comment: @wildplasser but the are needed to link the nodes of the rows together.

Comment: @wildplasser can you spot the problem in my code? or maybe point me in the right direction to solve it using this specific structures?

Comment: `for (j=0;j<col-1;j++)
       {
           newNode=createNode();
           temp->rows[i]->next=newNode;
       }` Is not appending, but replacing.