# Malloc of a structure failure inside a function

Tags: c, struct, malloc, nodes

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct cellNode {
        int cell;
        struct cellNode* next;
}   Node;

typedef struct  {
        int numRows;
        int numColumns;
        Node** rows;
}   Matrix;
```

and a function to add nodes in my code, but I get the 0xC0000005 error when i try to allocate memory for the node inside the function:

```
Node* createNode()
{
    int n;
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode==NULL)
        exit(1);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("n is %d\n",n);
    newNode->cell=n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

The function allocates memory for a node and returns it to another function that appends it to an array of nodes. so the call for the createNode function looks like this :

```
Matrix* MatrixAdder(int row, int col, char mat)
{
    int i,j;
    int value=0;
    Node* newNode=NULL;
    Matrix* temp = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    if (temp==NULL)
        exit (1);
    temp->numRows=row;
    temp->numColumns=col;
    temp->rows = malloc(row * sizeof(Node*));
    if (temp->rows==NULL)
        exit(1);
    for (i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter row %d data\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&value);
        temp->rows[i]->cell=value;
        for (j=0;j<col-1;j++)
        {

            newNode=createNode();
            temp->rows[i]->next=newNode;
            
        }
    }


}
```

I get this:

```
Enter row 0 data
2

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 6.525 s
Press any key to continue.
```

the function is able to receive the int but immediately fails at the malloc line.
the main just calles for the functions :

```
int main()

{
    int i;
    Matrix *A, *B, *C;
    int n,m,k;
    MatSize(&n,&m,&k); /*works fine*/
    A=MatrixAdder(n, m, 'A');
    B=MatrixAdder(m, k, 'B');

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you put this in a [mcve] so we can see the whole picture?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/W8bMsbx3W). Please provide a proper [mcve] or we will be unable to help.

Comment: The `createNode` function is correct, the problem is elsewhere in your code

Comment: @Jabberwocky but the error is from within this function so how is the problem elsewhere ?

Comment: Show us the "elsewhere" and we will point out how.

Comment: *but the error is from within this function so how is the problem elsewhere*  You corrupted memory somehow.  When your `malloc()` call steps on the land mine you planted when you corrupted memory your process blows up.

Comment: The shown code would output "n is %d\n". The shown output has something else. At a guess, the elsewhere does not call the shown code and uses something else, which is buggy, or misuses it. A [mre] would really help. Please provide one.

Comment: Your code and your output doesn't match. So most likely you didn't post your actual code.

Comment: CreateNode != newNode.

Comment: Why do you think the `newNode` is failing? Place a print statement just after `someNode=newNode();` and see what output you get.

Comment: @michaeldest Why don't you react to questions in the comments?

Comment: I am editing the question to better show the whole code, one minute please.

Comment: What is `Matrix`? Please show a [mcve]

Comment: finished editing.@4386427

Comment: `temp->rows[i]->cell=value;` You are assigning to an uninitialised pointer here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68065274/905902

Comment: @wildplasser but I allocated temp->rows with row*Nodes, what am i missing here ??

Comment: @wildplasser basically I need to implement a matrix using a struct that contains rows, each row has nodes linked in chain of values. cant figure it out and cant seems to find **anything** similar to that anywhere.

Comment: You allocated N pointers, not nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
temp->rows[i]->cell=value;
```

is wrong. `temp->rows[i]` is not pointing to any valid object.

You did allocate memory for `rows`, i.e.

```
temp->rows = malloc(row * sizeof(Node*));
```

but you never assigned any values to `row[0], row[1], ...` so you are dereferencing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was so frustraited from that , I allocated node memory inside of the i for and now everything works !!!

Comment: No, it is still wrong `temp->rows[i]->next=newNode;` reassigns the second node again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Works here:

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct cellNode {
        int cell;
        struct cellNode *next;
}   Node;

// and a function to add nodes in my code, but I get the 0xC0000005 error when i try to allocate memory for the node inside the function:

Node *createNode()
{
    int n;
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (newNode==NULL)
        exit(1);
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("n is %d\n",n);
    newNode->cell=n;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// The function allocates memory for a node and returns it to another function that appends it to an array of nodes. so the call for the createNode function looks like this :

int main(void)
{
Node *someNode=NULL;

printf("Enter row 0 data\n");
someNode = createNode();

printf("Some node: %d\n", someNode->cell);

return 0;
}
```